# How to display content where author matches connected user?

Tags: views, 8, users

is it possible to modify admin/content view to display only the content the connected user has created ?

If not , how to achieved that?

Comment: Since https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views is in core now, no problem.

Comment: i have acces to that view indeed but i can't find how to do the above

Comment: You would add the user id as a contextual argument, set to 'Current User'.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to kevin

with contextual filters , selecting fixed value:

author == id of connected user

[image]